# My raspberryPi 4 starts up Kodi, and I don’t know how to switch to my desktop

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, boot-issues, kodi

The first time I installed the Noobs software. I would choose between raspian and openelec(kodi). Now this menu is gone and I don’t now how to get it back. I tried reinstalling but didn’t work either. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Have you tried holding down `shift` while booting?

Comment: And plus, don't deal with `NOOBS`. Use the official raspberry pi image formatter.

Comment: Thank you @Unsigned_Arduino, the last time Installed it with the pi image formatter

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple types of software on you raspberry, can I have retropie, kodi and the desktop on one raspberry

Comment: If you used the image formatter have you overwritten the card?  I would look to berry-boot if you want to have multiple config son one card https://berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot Better still is one card per operating style (16Gb are a nice balance between cost and space I find).

Comment: I've done Kodi and the desktop on one card by installing both OS with NOOBS. When booting it asks which OS you want to boot.